# Angular Mat Table How to filter values using 2 conditions

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat table with 2 filter option conditions.
I can filter with one condition just like what the normal filter does on MatTableDatasource,
like if I select a teller name or a date alternating,

However I cannot filter if I put two filter condition like

Teller Name and her collection date today.

[image]

HTML

```
                <label>Teller Name: </label>
                  <select  
                   name="tellerName" 
                   (change)="applyFilter($any($event.target).value)">
                <option value="{{tellerList.collectorName}}"
                    *ngFor ="let tellerList of tellerList"
                >{{tellerList.collectorName}}</option>
                </select>   

                <label>Collection Date:</label>
                    <input 
                     type="date" 
                     name="collectionDate" 
                     (change)="applyFilter($any($event.target).value)"   
                    >
```

TS

```
  applyFilter(filterValue:string) {
    this.dataDepoSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

Datasource is coming from a firestore via an observable thru a service

```
 this.customerService.getDeposit().subscribe( depObs => {
      this.depositList = depObs;
      this.dataDepoSource = new MatTableDataSource(depObs);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filterPredicate` property of the `MatTableDataSource`, with this you can create your own `custom filter` to allow for different use cases.

So your custom filter function will look something like this:

```
filterPredicate = (data: any): boolean => {
   if (
     // create a separate function checkDate, to check if Date filter fulfills your criteria.
     // it should return a boolean.

     this.matchDate(data.collectionDate) &&
     // You can directly check for collector name as it would be a simple check
     data.collectorName.indexOf(this.searchedCollectorName) > -1
   )    {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
};
```

You'll have to bind your `dataSource` with the new custom `filterPredicate`

```
this.dataDepoSource = new MatTableDataSource(depObs);
this.dataDepoSource.filterPredicate = this.filterPredicate
```

You'll have to bind `searchedCollectorName` with the input field and the same for
`selectedDate`, so that your `filterPredicate` can have both the values if anyone filter is applied

You can use `Template Driven` or `Reactive Forms` to bind your `HTML` `input` and `select` with your `.ts`. If we use template driven. Your HTML will look something like this:

```
  <label>Teller Name: </label>
  <select name="tellerName" [(ngModel)]="searchCollectorName" (change)="applyFilter()">
     <option value="{{tellerList.collectorName}}" *ngFor ="let tellerList of tellerList">
      {{tellerList.collectorName}}
     </option>
  </select>   

  <label>Collection Date:</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" type="date" name="collectionDate" (change)="applyFilter()">
```

and finally You'll have to manually trigger `MatTableDataSource` filtering method
hence withe `applyFilter()` we'll simply do this in our `HTML`:

```
applyFilter():void {
   this.dataDepoSource.filter = 'filterApplied';
}
```